# listview in contraintlayout is not wrapping around

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using constraint layout to position my list I want my list to wrap its contents how ever  I don't want to grow too much and push the button at bottom. So I did the following

```
 <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvMyList"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/ibAdd"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ivStage" />
```

As you can see, I am setting it to have a bottom be contraint to the top of the bAdd button.

The issue here is my list always occupy the max size (meaning below stage button and above add button) even if it has one item.  How can I ensure that if it has one button then it just shrinks to that. If I do wrap_content around the hieght then it does not respect the constraint and moves beyond the bottom button

Thank you

Comment: Still looking for a solution?

Comment: Yea for that, for now  I just had to set it manually to specific szie